# How to optimize query by SUM of relations?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I have 3 simple tables

1. Invoices ( ~500k records )
2. Invoice items, one-to-many relation to invoices ( ~10 million records )
3. Invoice payments, one-to-many relation to invoices ( ~700k records )

Now, as simple as it sounds, I need to query for unpaid invoices.

Here is the query I am using:

```
select * from invoices
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(price) as totalAmount 
                FROM invoice_items 
                GROUP BY invoice_id) AS t1 
        ON t1.invoice_id = invoices.id
    LEFT JOIN  (SELECT invoice_id, SUM(payed_amount) as totalPaid 
                FROM invoice_payment_transactions 
                GROUP BY invoice_id) AS t2 
        ON t2.invoice_id = invoices.id
WHERE totalAmount > totalPaid
```

Unfortunately, this query takes around 30 seconds, so way to slow.
Of course I have indexes set for "invoice_id" on both payments and items.

When I "EXPLAIN" the query, I can see that mysql has to do a full table scan.
I also tried several other query approaches, using "EXISTS" or "IN" with subqueries, but I never got around the full table scan.

Pretty sure there is not much that can be done here ( except use some caching approach ), but maybe someone knows how to optimize this ?
I need this query to run in a +/-2 seconds max.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to everybody for trying. Please just know that I absolutely know how to adopt different caching strategies here, but this question is purely about optimizing this query !

Here are the ( simplified ) table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices`
(
    `id`          bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `created_at`  timestamp           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `date`        date                NOT NULL,
    `title`       enum ('M','F','Other')       DEFAULT NULL,
    `first_name`  varchar(191)                 DEFAULT NULL,
    `family_name` varchar(191)                 DEFAULT NULL,
    `street`      varchar(191)        NOT NULL,
    `postal_code` varchar(10)         NOT NULL,
    `city`        varchar(191)        NOT NULL,
    `country`     varchar(2)          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `invoice_items`
(
    `id`          bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `invoice_id`  bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `created_at`  timestamp           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `name`        varchar(191)                 DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` text                         DEFAULT NULL,
    `reference`   varchar(191)                 DEFAULT NULL,
    `quantity`    smallint(6)         NOT NULL,
    `price`       int(11)             NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `invoice_items_invoice_id_index` (`invoice_id`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `invoice_payment_transactions`
(
    `id`                     bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `invoice_id`             bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `created_at`             timestamp           NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
    `transaction_identifier` varchar(191)        NOT NULL,
    `payed_amount`           mediumint(9)                 DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `invoice_payment_transactions_invoice_id_index` (`invoice_id`),
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

Comment: Precompute the sums and store them in a summary table.

Comment: Yes, thank you ... but at the end, I consider this to be a "caching approach". That would work fine indeed, but I would have to change a lot of the existing code, to make sure these sums are updated on every change on any of the 3 models

Comment: I agree with that. But your query is doing table-scans. The other alternatives are delete some data or get a more powerful server.

Comment: can you add the SQL query to build the table structure for the tables you are using plz?

Comment: MySQL cannot optimize that query as it needs to do a table scan for invoice_items and invoice_payment_transactions. Add a payment status column to invoices. You can create a trigger that updates the status when payments arrive.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.  I think I can provide a change to the indexes to speed up the query.

Comment: I added the table definitions ... still very interested in how this query could be optimized !

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

Summary table by invoice_id and *day*.  (as Bill suggested)  [*Summary Tables*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables)

Plan B:

Change the design to be "current" and "history".  This is where the "payments" is a "history" of money changing hands.  Meanwhile "invoices" would be "current" in that it contains a "balance_owed" column.  This is a philosophy change; it could (should) be encapsulated in a client subroutine and/or a database Stored Procedure.

Plan C:  This may be useful if "most" of the invoices are paid off.

Have a flag in the invoices table to indicate paid-off.  That will prevent "most" of the JOINs from occurring.  (Well, adding that column is just as hard as doing Plan B.)

Comment: My question was purely about optimizing the query, but thank you for trying !